# Link multiple objects in one loop in emberjs

Tags: jquery, html, json, ember.js, web-deployment

I am new to EmberJS so i am having lot of issues and i haven't found many tutorials on internet. Here is the question.. I am creating an employee portal where i want to show an employee and it's manager on the same line. Here's the code

```
{{#each employee in model}}
      <tr>
      <td class="span2"><input type="checkbox" style="margin-left : 110px;"/></td>
      <td class="span2">{{#linkTo 'employee' employee}}{{employee.empId}}{{/linkTo}}</td>
      <td class="span2">{{employee.name}}</td>
      <td class="span2">{{employee.age}}</td>
      <td class="span2">{{employee.gender}}</td>
      <td class="span2">{{#linkTo 'employee' employee}}{{employee.mgrId}}{{/linkTo}}</td>
      <td class="span2">{{employee.package}}</td>
      <td class="span2">{{employee.address}}</td>
      <td class="span2">{{employee.phone}}</td>
      <td> <button {{action "deleteEmployee" employee}}> Delete </button></td>
      {{/each}}
      <tr>
```

I hope this gives a clear picture of how i am showing it on my html page. Now the problem is in the line where i am linking it to employee.mgrId but it is still showing the same employee detail.

And here is the code of .JS file.

```
App.EmployeeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(param) {
        console.log(param.employee_id);
        return App.Employees[param.employee_id];
    },
    setupController : function(controller,model) {
        this.controllerFor('employee.edit').set('model',controller.get('model'));
    }
});
```

So please help me in resolving the problem as how should i approach to get the details of Manager.

Here is one of the sample from Employee database.

```
"1" : App.Employee.create({
        "id" : "1",
        "empId" : "emp1",
        "name" : "Employee 1", 
        "age" : "23",
        "dob" : "17/12/89",
        "gender" : "male",
        "doj" : "9/1/12",
        "mgrId" : "emp6",
        "package" : "300000",
        "address" : "address 1",
        "phone" : "9999999999"
    }),
```

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your linkto is wrong for the employer

it should be the mgrUniqueId being passed into the linkto helper, where the mgrUniqueId is the id used for querying an employee (probably 6, if the pattern seems to match).  I'd modify your data to include the actual unique identifier of the manager.

```
<td class="span2">{{#linkTo 'employee' employee.mgrUniqueId}}{{employee.mgrId}}{{/linkTo}}</td>
```